# MySQL. Оптимизация тяжелого запроса

Tags: mysql, долгий-запрос

Есть такой запрос:

```
select max(case when consumer.dateTo=CUST.GetDateTimeMax() then consumer.dateFrom else consumer.dateTo end) max_date
    from CUST.EntityRuleLink consumer
    join CUST.EntityPropertyValue p on p.entityId=consumer.parentEntityId
    join CUST.EntityPropertyValue c on c.entityId=consumer.childEntityId
    where p.entityPropertyKindId=14482
    and p.value=30508420
    and c.entityPropertyKindId=14478
    and c.value=41109007
    and consumer.hierarchyRelationId=1026;
```

Его план такой:

```
 "id"   "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "p" "ref"   "entityId,entityPropertyKindId,entityIdShortIndex"  "entityPropertyKindId"  "8" "const" "22824489"  "Parent of 3 pushed join@1; Using where"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "consumer"  "ref"   "childEntityId,parentEntityId"  "parentEntityId"    "9" "CUST.p.entityId"   "15"    "Child of 'p' in pushed join@1; Using where with pushed condition"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "c" "ref"   "entityId,entityPropertyKindId,entityIdShortIndex"  "entityIdShortIndex"    "8" "CUST.consumer.childEntityId"   "20"    "Child of 'consumer' in pushed join@1; Using where"
```

Данный запрос отрабатывает более 20 минут. Есть ли какие-то способы его ускорить? Подскажите, куда копать?

Comment: Первое что нужно сделать для оптимизации это добавить индексы для поиска, если таковых конечно еще нету.

Comment: @user287120, индексы есть. Судя по плану, он их использует

Comment: По поводу индекстов, еще обратите внимание, здесь поля value скорее всего могут содержать одинаковые значения. Поэтому индекс одиночка для них будет неэфективный, если конечно таковой есть. Здесь нужно создать мерж индекс EntityPropertyValue(entityPropertyKindId, value)

Comment: Индексы не правильные. У вас по первой строке плана показан перебор 22 млн записей. Вам надо сделать такой индекс, который бы выбирал минимум записей. Например по полю value. или составной (entityPropertyKindId, value). А индекс entityPropertyKindId вообще не имеет смысла. Что бы сказать более точно, надо видеть полную структуру таблиц и статистику данных.

Comment: @Mike, создал индекс: `CREATE INDEX vEpv_index ON CUST.EntityPropertyValue (value,entityPropertyKindId) USING BTREE ;`. Никак не помогло, перебор остался тем же самым

Comment: Смотрите план выполнения, начал ли оптимизатор его использовать, каково его предсказание по количеству записей

Comment: @Mike, да, оптимизатор начал его использовать для обоих джоинов: `entityId,entityPropertyKindId,entityIdShortIndex,vEpv_index`. Предсказание осталось тем-же 22824489

Comment: хм. это странно. сколько у вас реально записей с данными value и property